# Error in grid.draw(grob.list) : object 'grob.list' not found when using VennDiagram package

Tags: r

I am trying to create a Venn Diagram but scale the circles differently based on a different variable, in this case: ar.

Here is my example code:

```
B <- subset(data, data$factor1 == "Y")
A <- subset(data, data$factor2 == "Y")
ar <- c(sum(B$dollars), sum(A$dollars))
B <- B$unique_id
A <- A$unique_id
venn.diagram(x = list("B" = B, "A" = A), filename = "qualify_hs.tiff",
                     + fill = c("yellow", "cornflowerblue"), cat.default.pos = "text",
                     + print.mode = "percent", direct.area = TRUE, area.vector = ar)
```

This does not seem to be working and is giving me this error:

```
Error in grid.draw(grob.list) : object 'grob.list' not found
```

I have not been able to find a solution or any realy documentation on using the direct.area and area.vector options in the VennDiagram package.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your area.vector needs to be the same length as the number of regions (ie A + B + their interaction  = 3, you only have 2)

Comment: @user20650 I added this and now have
`ar <- c(sum(B$dollars), sum(A$dollars), sum(C$dollars))`
where C is the intersection of A and B.  Doing this rescales the regions and changes their associated values from the number of observations to the scale.